# deleted postgres files on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I was cleaning out some files in `/home/postgres`, and accidentally deleted the directory named `10`.  Now nothing works.  Here is the error I get when I try to run `psql` as the `postgres` user:

```
    psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What did I break, and how do I fix it?

Other info:

- This is a scratch database, so I am not very concerned about recovering old stored databases.  However, it would be easier for me if I could.
- I thought about doing an uninstall/reinstall using apt-get, but since things are in an unstable state, I thought it would be better to get some advice first.
- I am running postgres 10 on Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you deleted: was it the database data or the database software?

Since `psql` still works, I suspect that the database software is still there, and you deleted the data. Then the only way to recover is to restore from a backup.

No, there is no way to "undelete" data.